# Why do i need add a namespace prefix before return types of a function?

Tags: c++

I'm writing some C++ codes. In these codes, there are nested namespace, like A::B::C. A, B, C are namespaces. I define a type TYPEA in A, and again redefine TYPEA in B. According to my understanding, A::B::TYPEA will shield A::TYPEA. But why i still add namespace prefix A::B::TYPEA in functions' return type?

```
namespace A
{

typedef int TYPEA;

namespace B
{

class ClassB
{
public:
    typedef int TYPEA;

    TYPEA foo();
};

ClassB::TYPEA ClassB::foo()
{
    // ...
}

}
}
```

Accroding to my understanding, A::B::ClassB::TYPEA will shield A::TYPEA, why i cannot define foo like that:

```
TYPEA ClassB::foo()
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "shield"? What are you trying to do here? Care to write out a more meaningful example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply one of the rules of C++ name lookup.  The leading return type of a function is not within the scope of that function, so in that context, the compiler does not search for the name `TYPEA` in the scope of `ClassB`.

A *trailing* return type is within the scope of the function though, so `TYPEA` *will* be found in the scope of `ClassB` if you use a trailing return:

```
auto ClassB::foo() -> TYPEA
{
    // ...
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b43883a4818ed7a)

Answer (score 0):

Due to scoping, `TYPEA` is considered `A::B::ClassB::TYPEA` everywhere inside of the class declaration and method definitions and `A::TYPEA` elsewhere inside namespace `A`.

```
namespace A
{

typedef int TYPEA;

namespace B
{
/*
TYPEA refers to A::TYPEA
*/
class ClassB
{
public:
    typedef int TYPEA;

    TYPEA foo();
    /*
    TYPEA refers to A::B::ClassB::TYPEA
    */
};
/*
TYPEA refers to A::TYPEA
*/
ClassB::TYPEA ClassB::foo()
{
    // ...
    /*
    TYPEA refers to A::B::ClassB::TYPEA
    */
}
};
/*
TYPEA refers to A::TYPEA
*/
}
}
```

> Accroding to my understanding, A::B::ClassB::TYPEA will shield A::TYPEA, why i cannot define foo like that:
>
> ```
> TYPEA ClassB::foo()
> {
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Actually, for your particular case, you can. Since both `TYPEA`'s are typedef-ed to `int`, the code compiles whether or not you prefix the return type with `ClassB`.

```
ClassB::TYPEA ClassB::foo() {}
// resolves to
//   int ClassB::foo() {}

----

TYPEA ClassB::foo() {}
// resolves to
//   int ClassB::foo() {}
```

The two signatures are the same. Now, if instead the types are *different*, then the signatures won't resolve and you'll get a compile error. For example:

```
namespace A
{

typedef double TYPEA;      // double

namespace B
{

class ClassB
{
public:
    typedef int TYPEA;      // int

    TYPEA foo();
};

ClassB::TYPEA ClassB::foo()    // not the same as `TYPEA ClassB::foo()` !!!  
{
    // ...
}

}
}
```

Here, the namespace prefix is needed to disambiguate `TYPEA` and specify the one typedef-ed under `ClassB`.